# Конвертер валют на минималках. Number-ом обернул все вводимые данные, но выдает NaN

Tags: javascript, dom, html-select

Всем привет! Есть следующая задача: "Реализуйте калькулятор валют. Есть два селекта - селект с исходной валюты, селект с той валютой, в которую мы хотим перевести деньги, инпут, в который вводится сумма для обмена. Курсы валют храните в массиве. Сделайте так, чтобы в селектах нельзя было выбрать две одинаковых валюты."

А вот собственно мое решение на коленках. которое выдает NaN. Как правильно прописать Number, чтобы получить корректный ответ. Возможно ошибка в let, потому что не полностью понял его использование в отличие от var. Но все это не точно :).

```
    <select class="currentCurrency"></select>
    <select class="transferCurrency"></select>
    <label> Введите число: <input class="inputSum" type="number"></label>
    <button class="btn">Конвертировать</button>
    <div class="output"></div>

    let curCur = document.querySelector('.currentCurrency');
    let transCur = document.querySelector('.transferCurrency');
    let inputSum = document.querySelector('.inputSum');
    let btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
    let show = document.querySelector('.output');

    let arr = {
        Доллар: [1],
        Тенге: [381.19],
        Рубль: [62.92],
    };

    let currency = Object.keys(arr);
    fillSelect(curCur, currency);
    fillSelect(transCur, currency);

    curCur.addEventListener('change', numOneValue);
    function numOneValue() {
        let num1 = Number(arr[this.value]);
        return num1;
    }

    curCur.addEventListener('change', numTwoValue);
    function numTwoValue() {
        let num2 = Number(arr[this.value]);
        return num2;
    }

    btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
        show.innerHTML = numOneValue() * Number(inputSum.value) * numTwoValue();
    });

    function fillSelect(select, arr) {
        for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            select.add(new Option(arr[i]));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Comment: Вы правы, сейчас поправлю)

Answer (score 0):

Уберите квадратные скобки из

```
let arr = {
    Доллар: [1],
    Тенге: [381.19],
    Рубль: [62.92],
};
```

Зачем они там?

---

> так сказано же - хранить в массиве :)

Хорошо. Тогда:

```
function numOneValue() {
    let num1 = arr[this.value][0];
    return num1;
}
```

---

```
btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    show.innerHTML = Number(inputSum.value) / numOneValue.bind(curCur)() * numTwoValue.bind(transCur)();
});
```

Comment: так сказано же - хранить в массиве :)

Comment: типо это объект, разве нет?

Comment: @МирасТекесбаев Что есть "типо"?

Comment: объект arr ,  в нем есть ключи и значения

Comment: let arr = {
    Доллар: 1,
    Тенге: 381.19,
    Рубль: 62.92,
};
Так надо писать или так let arr = [Доллар: 1, Тенге: 381.19, Рубль: 62.92];

Comment: @МирасТекесбаев Первый вариант. Второй вариант - вызовет ошибку парсера.